# Grails: field uniqueness within domain hierarchy

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

Assume that we have such domain hierarchy:

```
class Category {
...
    static hasMany = [groups: Group]
...
}

class Group {
...
    static belongsTo = [category: Category]
    static hasMany = [items: Item]
...
}

class Item {
...
    Integer value
    static belongsTo = [group: Group]
...
}
```

The field *value* in the *Item* class should be unique within one *Category*. How can we achieve this?

I tried to write a custom validator using criteria, but finally I got a "don't flush the Session after an exception occurs" Hibernate error. Is there a better way to check this constraint?

Comment: I don't think there is cool Grails way of doing that since Category is one level above Item's parent, Group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm maybe

```
class Item {
    ...
    Integer value
    static belongsTo = [group: Group, category: Category]
    static constraints = {group value: 'category'}
    ...
}
```

Also you could add custom validator to check if parent group belongs to the same category.

Did not test it.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Introducing a redundant `category` field eliminates the necessity to write an awkward custom validator for the `value` field. Thank you!